# HTML/XML Parser for Java

Tags: java, html, xml, dom, parsing

What HTML parsers have the following features:

- Fast
- Thread-safe
- Reliable and bug-free
- Parses HTML and XML
- Handles erroneous HTML
- Has a DOM implementation
- Supports HTML4, JavaScript, and CSS tags
- Relatively simple, object-oriented API

What parser you think is better?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "support HTML4, javascript and CSS" ? A parser is just that, a parser, it won't interpret your page. If you want to simulate a browser, please rephrase your question.

Comment: No. Some parsers do not understand things like CSS. This is what I mean.

Comment: If CSS is in a <style> tag, it will be interpreted as text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) is the best choice. Apache has recently extracted many sub-projects out of the existing projects and made them public. Tika is one of them that was previously a component of Apache Lucene. Because of Apache's support and reputation and the widely-used parent project Lucene it must be a very good choice. Furthermore, it is open-source.

A brief introduction from Apache Tika web site:

> The Apache Tika™ toolkit detects and extracts metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries.

And the supported formats are:

> ```
> HyperText Markup Language
> XML and derived formats
> Microsoft Office document formats
> OpenDocument Format
> Portable Document Format
> Electronic Publication Format
> Rich Text Format
> Compression and packaging formats
> Text formats
> Audio formats
> Image formats
> Video formats
> Java class files and archives
> The mbox format
> ```

Comment: Apache Tika is an excellent suggestion. Even if you are not interested in reading XML/HTML/MS DOC formats you can just specify "text/plain". It will stream in the data so it doesn't need to preload the whole file first. List of benefits: http://tika.apache.org/1.4/parser.html Article with sample code: http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/314389/Content-mining-with-Apache-Tika

Comment: I came for a solid HTML Parser, and left with one that I won't have to spend the time to generalize. I love this game.

Answer (score 16):

Check out [Web Harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/). It's both a library you can use and a data extraction tool, which sounds to me that's exactly what you want to do. You create XML script files to instruct the scraper how to extract the information you need and from where. The provided GUI is very useful to quickly test the scripts.

Check out the [project's samples page](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/samples.php) to see if it's a good fit for what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1 for Web Harvest -- if you are trying to do page scraping it is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

The best known are [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) and [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

NekoHTML is based on Xerces, and provides a simple adaptable [SAXParser](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/cyberneko/html/parsers/SAXParser.html) which implements [XMLReader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html) JavaSE interface.

JTidy is more intented into formatting your html code into something XML-valid, but is still very useful as an XML parser, producing a DOM tree if needed.

You could have a look at [this list](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) for other alternatives.

Another choice could be to use [hpricot](http://github.com/whymirror/hpricot) through jRuby.

Comment: Why? which features do they have?

Comment: SAX is not what I want and main purpose of JTidy is cleaning an XML. Are you sure that it does what i want better than others?

Comment: what do you want exactly, then ?

Comment: It should be DOM based. and I want extraction as it's main job not transformation.

Comment: It doesn't matter what its "main" job is, as long as it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 6):

[Validator.nu's HTML parser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/), definitely. It's an implementation of the HTML5 parsing algorithm, and Gecko is in the process of replacing its own HTML parser with a C++ translation of this one.

Answer (score 1):

Well:

there aren't so many good HTML parsers in java as you need, but here are some alternatives:
http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Very few of them support Javascript. Actually, I think you'll have to do this part on your own using Rhino (http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

Answer (score 1):

I think that [HTML Cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) is what you're looking for. See its [announcement](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=50059) on TheServerSide to see how it compare to JTidy, TagSoup, NekoHtml.

Comment: But this is also for transforming into well XMLs. My main goal is extracting data from it.

Comment: @Shayan So what? Doesn't it allow you to extract data from it? Doesn't it offer DOM manipulation? Doesn't it allow to parse nasty HTML? I don't get you.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to look at doing something like running Mozilla in headless mode. Here is a [link](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/headless-html-rendering-engine/) to get you started, I am sure you can use Google to find out more information.