# What's a suitable html parser for Android?

Tags: android

What's a suitable html parser for Android?

Comment: If you are willing to extract data from the html perhaps a simple regex can help you.

Answer (score 6):

It depends what you want to do.  If you actually want to process html, there are lots of html parsers in Java that should work.  [Here are some.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)  [Here are some more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java).  If you just want to display html, you can do very basic stuff with the [HTML class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) or you can display an entire web page using [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).