# Html Parsing in android

Tags: android, html-parsing

I have a Html Response for my application that I need to parse ultimately. Is there any way to perform the Html Parsing in android application. I have searched net a lot but couldn't found anything I was looking for.

Can anyone have a clue to do the same?

Thanks,
david

Comment: Why do you want to parse a HTML file?

Comment: please refer this link:
http://www.anddev.org/html_parsing_in_android_how-t10749.html

Comment: @Chromium - because the response for the links that I am getting from the server is in the Html form. And I need only some specific data to get displayed in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

david do check [HTML class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

```
Html.fromHtml("<a href=http://saurabh-nigam.blogspot.com/>myblogt</a>")
```

And also this post ['html parsers for android'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167611/whats-a-suitable-html-parser-for-android/2169719#2169719) links some parsers

Answer (score 2):

We are using both jericho and htmlcleaner in our project. We have made some changes (big and small) to htmlcleaner. And we have added better error handling to jericho.

Our [Jericho](https://github.com/amplafi/jericho-html) and [htmlcleaner](https://github.com/amplafi/htmlcleaner) versions are available on github.

(In answer to why we forked: we needed some fixes that the original developers were unwilling or unavailable to incorporate into their version. This was not a willing fork. )