# Android: Fill Form Data and Extract HTML

Tags: java, android, html-parsing

I have a very simple problem:

Using java (and android) I am trying to go to a certain website (URL given), fill in form fields, login (i.e. clicking a button) and then extract the HTML source of the resulting page.

I have tried already to use headless browsers and htmlparsers like HTML Unit and Selenium, but the jars always conflict and they don't seem to work with Android.

How else would I go about doing this? (Also, I need this to happen without the user needing to see a WebView or page, so in the background).

Answer (score 0):

do check [HTML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class

```
Html.fromHtml("<a href=http://saurabh-nigam.blogspot.com/>myblogt</a>")
```

And also this post '[html parsers for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591029/html-parsing-in-android)' links some parsers