# Selenium, WebDriver, HtmlUnit equivalent for android

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver, html-parsing, htmlunit

This is what I'm trying to do:
1. I have a tablet and I want to connect to the university's wi-fi to access internet
2. Connection to the internet won't work unless you open a browse
3. You are automatically redirected to a university username-password page
4. You type in your university credentials and boom => you have internet

Problem??? I hate to have to put my password every single day and although chrome for android can store it I still have to open a browser, etc. etc. etc.

Solution:
Use Selenium, WebDriver, HtmlUnit or some sort of headless browser to programmatically fill in the login form in the background.

Problem 2: These headless browsers don't work on Android (Or I haven't been able to make them work)

Does anyone know of a simple headless browser that works on Android devices, one that can fill a simple form and submit it? Are there other alternatives to what I want to do?

Thx in advance for the help.

Some related Questions: [HttpUnit/HtmlUnit equivalent for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721544/httpunit-htmlunit-equivalent-for-android), [Android: Fill Form Data and Extract HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997546/android-fill-form-data-and-extract-html), [Html Parsing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591029/html-parsing-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

How does the University validate you once you've logged in? e.g. is it based on setting cookies in your web browser? What happens if you login with another web browser once you've authenticated in the first one?

Once you know how it authenticates you, you should be able to devise a suitable approach. For instance, if it's device-wide authentication e.g. based on your mac address then perhaps you can write a simple Android app that embeds a WebView, and/or plain old HTTP request / response programming in Java. If, however, it's browser based then you either need to login (automagically) with the browser you then want to use, or find a way to insert the relevant cookie(s) into the browser that you want to use for web browsing.