# Reading HTML+JavaScript using Java

Tags: java, javascript, html

I can read the HTML contents via http (for example, http://www.foo.com) using Java (with URL and BufferedReader classes). However, a couple of them contain JavaScript. My current app cannot process JavaScript.

What's the best way to read HTML content with JavaScript using Java?

I am open using other languages if it is easier.

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE - Clarification:

A couple HTML contents are generated dynamically using JavaScript. I can see the result (in pure HTML after the JavaScript processing) when viewing them on a browser.

On the other hand, when my Java app retrieves the HTML contents, it says that there is no JavaScript on my app.

Ideally, I want to be able to get the same result as on the browser using my Java app.

Thanks for everyone's response.

Comment: What are you doing with the contents returned by a URL after reading from it? Are you evaluating the JavaScript?

Comment: Not sure that I correctly understand your question. You can use [SWT Browser widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html). It can render HTML and supports JavaScript.

Comment: @pion What do you mean by "it says that there is no JavaScript on my app". Who says that ? Is it the HTML you got which contains this exact text ? Then you should consider modifying your User Agent String to get the correct content first. HTMLUnit can help you for that and is definitely the best way to go.

Comment: I have same proplem , can u help me ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781322/java-program-to-read-a-html-page-and-save-its-content-use-javascript?noredirect=1#comment31149974_20781322

Comment: @pion did my answer helped?

Answer (score 2):

HtmlUnit has good JavaScript support and it should (almost) parse the HTML as a web browser.

- http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/
- http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Cobra (http://lobobrowser.org/cobra/getting-started.jsp) will fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

For just HTML parsing you can use HTMLParser (org.htmlparser). However from the way you described your problem, it seems you need a browser, because executing is totally different than just parsing. Cheers.

Answer (score -3):

With no doubt you need to use **Java html parser**:

- [Java Open Source HTML Parsers](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)
- [Which Html Parser is best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)
- [HTML/XML Parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java)
- [HTML PARSER in java [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084148/html-parser-in-java)

Comment: 99 of 100 HTML parsers in Java don't understand/execute JavaScript. Please be more specific.