# Find content of href link and URL in Java

Tags: java, href

I want to parse this link :

```
<a href="http://www.google.fr">Link to google</a>
```

In order to get two results:

```
Link = "http://www.google.fr"
LinkName = "Link to google"
```

I really don't know how to do this, is there a library in Java to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: You can use XML parser.. then parse that 'a' node and retrieve values.

Comment: For very simple HTML, you may just use the default HTMLParser provided with the JVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do.

```
public class Parse
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String h = " <a href=\"http://www.google.fr\">Link to google</a>";
    int n = getIndexOf(h, '"', 0);

    String[] a = h.substring(n).split(">");
    String url = a[0].replaceAll("\"", "");
    String value = a[1].replaceAll("</a", "");

    System.out.println(url + " - " + value);
  }

  public static int getIndexOf(String str, char c, int n)
  {
    int pos = str.indexOf(c, 0);
    while (n-- > 0 && pos != -1)
    {
      pos = str.indexOf(c, pos + 1);
    }
    return pos;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is bad practise. You should avoid depending on character positioning. See Nurlan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) parser:

example:

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```