# Html parser with java

Tags: java, html, parsing

I have a simple question:
Let's supose i have the next span:

```
<span class="data" id="random">
Here the piece of string i need
</span>
```

How can i get what's inside of the span?

Thx! :D

Comment: Google for "Java HTML parser"

Comment: check the javadocs for HTMLParser

Comment: Using DOM parser and getting data you need from it.

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. You should invest some minutes and read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html

Comment: -1 sorry, question needs more info ( also hints that you may mean javascript rather than java )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Parser is a HTML parser for Java.

http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yep, HTML Parser would do. But i don't want a whole project to work with; I just need a simple script that works fine...

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), is an HTML parser for Java.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("LINK_TO_YOUR_PAGE").get();
Elements random = doc.select("#random");
System.out.println(random.html());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to use core classes rather than an HTML parser, you could use a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) to capture the contents of the span.

The "related" section for this question shows a lot of people [asking similar parsing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java).