# How do I filter a HTTP get response?

Tags: java, http-get

I have learnt how to create a HTTP Get request method to retrieve data from a URL, but I would like to filter the response to only give me a list of the links on the webpage.

For example, if the HTML contained the following text:

```
<link href="http://www.thompsons.co.uk">
```

then it should print out:

http://www.thompsons.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jsoup:

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend that you DO NOT use regexes to "parse" HTML.  Unless you have control over the formatting of the web pages you are processing, a solution based on regexes is liable to be fragile and buggy.

Instead, use a permissive HTML parser.  This Question gives a number of alternatives:  [HTML/XML Parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

You read in the whole data fully, then parse it with regexp to extract the links. Read more here: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-extract-html-links-with-regular-expression/

Comment: Ermm ... did someone mention Tony the Poney??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Depends on the case. I've used regexp when I've parsed links and/or other content from specific sources. If the case is to parse generic links, then perhaps another approach is better.