# Reading data from a website with HTTP GET and regular expression

Tags: java, httpwebrequest

I have a PHP script which prints something like "online" "offline" and a specific number which change in a specific time. I found an example for a http get request, and now I need something like Regex I think, right? :o Does anyone have a tutorial or can give me a simple example?

The code of the request:

```
String urlString;
urlString = "hear is my url^^";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream IS = conn.getInputStream();
```

The Inputstream IS is the "sourcecode" of the website, right?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The IS contains the HTML source. You should consider using a HTML parsing library to extract the data. Regex is going to be brittle. There are many html parsers out there. Look at the below SO post

[HTML/XML Parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont need to use `URLConnection` to get the data from PHP script.
You can use `Jsoup` library to get data from PHP script and using this library you can parse the data as you want.
You will get it from here

[Jsoup API](http://jsoup.org/download)

and here is how to use it.

[Cookbook for Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

Comment: I included the jar of Jsoup and wrote this code

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("my url^^").get(); String title = doc.title(); TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testView); tv.setText(title);

But my program totally crashes :/ Do you have an idea?

Comment: What error you are getting?
You can try Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("your url"),int timeoutMillis ) instead of "Document doc = Jsoup.connect("my url^^").get() "....