# Java: Parse html file and extract text

Tags: java, parsing

I want to parse an `HTML` file and store the bold text (inside `<b>` tags). One solution is to read the file line by line and split or use `RegEx`. This means that I should store the entire page in a `String` variable? If I don't save it in a variable then I have no guarantee that the start of the tag and the end of it are on the same line.

What solution do you suggest?

Comment: Possible duplication of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084148/html-parser-in-java)!

Comment: Attempting to parse HTML with a regex is generally a *bad idea* and will lead to nothing but tears. But if you insist, yes, if you need to match across lines that's one way to do it. You can also deal with just reading it line by line if you keep track of a state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML/XML Parser for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 5):

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the contents

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Comment: Why would you not want to use a reliable third party library?  That's like saying "I want to connect to a database, but I don't want to use jdbc".

Comment: I would argue that there are reasons/scenarios for not wanting to have external dependencies but ... this isn't one of them.

Comment: @david99world because it is a project I have for university :)

Comment: @Andrew Could you elaborate a bit why universities don't like third party library? Is it about politics? I don't get it but I'm keen to know

Comment: Its probably because they want you to learn about the specific process and the best way to learn is to do.

Answer (score 0):

> it is a project I have for university

Use `HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback`