# Does Java have a built-in library for Analytic Hierarchy Process(jAHP) and HTML parser?

Tags: java, html-parsing, ahp

I'm new to Java and would like to ask whether does Java has a built-in library for Analytic Hierarchy Process(AHP) and HTML parser?

If there is what's library syntax?

I've read somewhere there's lots of HTML parser for Java. Which is the best parser that able to parse HTTPS?

Comment: http://jsoup.org/ is a good HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "built-in" implementation of AHP in Java.  There are third party implementations though; e.g. Google found these for me:

- http://www.di.unipi.it/~morge/software/JAHP.html
- http://pooyandeh.ca/blog/?p=66
- http://code.google.com/p/ahpfree

(You'll need to check them out for yourself ...)

Comment: Oh. I thought there is. No wonder I searched for hours but couldn't get the library.

Comment: See the other answers.  That part of your question is asking for a library recommendation which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Got it. Thanks by the way for the AHP part.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've seen so far is HtmlCleaner:

> HtmlCleaner is open-source HTML parser written in Java. HTML found on
>   Web is usually dirty, ill-formed and unsuitable for further
>   processing. For any serious consumption of such documents, it is
>   necessary to first clean up the mess and bring the order to tags,
>   attributes and ordinary text. For the given HTML document, HtmlCleaner
>   reorders individual elements and produces well-formed XML. By default,
>   it follows similar rules that the most of web browsers use in order to
>   create Document Object Model. However, user may provide custom tag and
>   rule set for tag filtering and balancing.

For other html parsers see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java).

Comment: Can it parse secured HTTP? What I mean is that can it parse HTTPS? Because when I use C++ library it couldn't parse HTTPS due to secured protocol.

Comment: Downloading stuff via HTTPS and parsing HTML are *orthogonal* problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this [java html parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

It is faster and easy to use with java.

Comment: Can it parse HTTPS? Because my project requires me to parse HTTPS.